# Power BI Custom Column: Matching Dates and Customer ID in Different Tables

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm currently working with some email data and in this data I have two tables: "Sends" and "Opens". Both tables have the date of the send or open by Customer ID.

[image: Example Image]

Ideally, I'd like to designate in a new column if a send date matches that of an open date for that specific customer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the following steps:

Create a concatenated field of Customer ID and Event Date in both the "Sends" and "Opens" table:

```
Key = CONCATENATE(Opens[Customer ID],Opens[Event Date])
Key = CONCATENATE(Sends[Customer ID],Sends[Event Date])
```

Create a relationship between the "Sends" and "Opens" tables by using the key variables. You can do this by selecting "Manage Relationships" under the "Modelling" tab.

Create a calculated column in the "sends" table using the following formula:

```
Open Date = IF(RELATED(Opens[Customer ID])=BLANK(),"No","Yes")
```

This should give you the desired result. Hope this helps.

Comment: In general it is preferred to avoid usinh calculated columns. Instead, it is preferred to modify the data source in the data warehouse or using power query when reading the data